# How to create a pvc based on the postgres initdb directory?

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes

I am running a docker image that has postgres 14 yum dependencies. I have created the docker image and have a start script that executes the following:

```
PGDATA="/var/lib/pgsql/14/data"
sudo -u postgres "$PGHOME/bin/initdb" --pgdata=$PGDATA
```

I am trying to create a pvc in kubernetes so that the PGDATA directory can be stateful. Right now if the pod restarts then there is no persistence. I've used the following statefulset:

```
          volumeMounts:
          - name: postgres-data
            mountPath: /var/lib/pgsql/14/data
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-data-pvc
```

Everytime I try to do this the pod restarts and mentions that the /var/lib/pgsql/14/data does not exist. Anyone have suggestions on this?

Comment: The standard Docker Hub `postgres` image handles this automatically (by running `initdb` in its entrypoint script); can you use that?

Comment: That would be my choice as well. But we are using a custom baked image for various reasons such as bdr. What are the challenges with what I am trying to do? I've added pvc 's for other applications for state keeping purposes but this seems more complex. Perhaps a init container needs to be used so that the postgres metadata exists before hand in the above PGDATA?

Comment: Do you have a more complete example?  Have you instrumented this script to verify that it's actually being run, and to see what's in the data directory before you run `initdb`?